# Pasar valores en razor a javaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en asp.net. Lo que pasa es que necesito acceder a un valor que me trae el razor, para posteriormente usarlo en un script pero no sé cómo combinar razor en javascript. Sé que de javascript a razor no es posible, pero de razor a javascript, sí. Necesito pasar un valor que me trae `@model` a mi `switch`.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcFrontBolsaTrabajo.Models.ParaProcReportes.PostulacionesXCandidatoModel>


@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutCandidato.cshtml";
}


@{
ViewBag.Title = "PostulacionesXCandidato";
}


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; margin-right:5%;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TituloVacante)
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombresoc)
                </p>
                <p>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombreciu)
                </p>
                <p>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaPostulacionvc)
                </p>
                <div class="second circle"></div>
                <strong>

                </strong>
            </div>
      
    }


    @section Scripts{
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="/Content/jquery-circle-progress/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>
    <script>

    switch () {
        case 25:
            $("#divMisPostulaciones").removeClass("SubMenuCandidato");
            $("#divMisPostulaciones").addClass("SubMenuCandidatoB");


            $('.second.circle').circleProgress({
                value: 1,
                startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                reverse: true,
                progress: 1.0
            }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress) {
                var contador = Math.round(100 * progress);
                if (contador == 25) {
                    $('div').find('strong').html(Math.round(100 * progress) + '<i>% CV visto</i>')
                };
            });
            break;

        case 50:
            $("#divMisPostulaciones").removeClass("SubMenuCandidato");
            $("#divMisPostulaciones").addClass("SubMenuCandidatoB");


            $('.second.circle').circleProgress({
                value: 1,
                startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                reverse: true,
                progress: 1.0
            }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress) {
                var contador = Math.round(100 * progress);
                if (contador == 25) {
                    $('div').find('strong').html(Math.round(100 * progress) + '<i>% CV visto</i>')
                };
            });

            break;

    }
</script>
```

}

Comment: que valor o valores necesitas?

Comment: una propiedad de mi Model, como en el foreach que tengo necesito acceder a item.valor solo que en javascript no en el html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder de esta manera

```
var modelo = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Asi tienes todos los valores de tu modelo en una variable javascript con formato JSON, de modo que puedes acceder

```
modelo.TituloVacante
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude resolverlo con tu solución.

Comment: excelente @RobertoDominguez, me alegro!

Answer (score 0):

Agregarlo a la pagina con input hidden asi:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Property)
```